# TrueQ returning False on true statement

Tags: expression-test, logic

Why does `TrueQ` return `False` on the following?

```
TrueQ[Log[2]/Log[8] == 1/3]
(* False *)
```

Shouldn't that be `True`? We can clearly see that the math checks out.

```
Log[2]/Log[8] // N
(* 0.333333 *)

8^(1/3)
(* 2 *)
```

Comment: `TrueQ[Log[2]/Log[8] == 1/3]` returns `True` with version 10 on Windows 7.

Comment: I get `False` from V9, but `True` from V10.

Comment: `TrueQ[N[Log[2]/Log[8]] == 1/3]` returns `True`.. :) Or `TrueQ[Log[2.]/Log[8] == 1/3]`.

Comment: I get `False` with version 8.0.4 and `True` with v.10.0.0 under Win7 x64.

Comment: I get `TrueQ[Log[2.]/Log[8] == 1/3]` as `True` in M9. And `False` for `TrueQ[Log[2]/Log[8] == 1/3]` in M9. Both returns `True` in M10.

Answer (score 9):

[`TrueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrueQ.html) does *not* attempt to resolve equivalencies:

> `TrueQ` will return `True` only if the input is explicitly `True`
>
> You can use `TrueQ` to "assume" that a test fails when its outcome is not clear.

Consider:

```
eq = D[Integrate[1/(x^3 + 1), x], x] == 1/(1 + x^3)
```

> ```
> 1/(3 (1 + x)) - (-1 + 2 x)/(6 (1 - x + x^2)) + 2/(3 (1 + 1/3 (-1 + 2 x)^2)) == 1/(1 + x^3)
> ```

This is *not* explicitly `True` – it is an equation, and `TrueQ` will yield `False`, but you can [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html):

```
Simplify[eq]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

In older versions use Simplify

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"

```
TrueQ[Log[2]/Log[8] == 1/3]
```

> False

```
TrueQ[Log[2]/Log[8] == 1/3 // Simplify]
```

> True

Comment: Using `Simplify` works with newer versions, too including 10.4.

Comment: @murray - Yes. But it is not needed then. This was to address a workaround for earlier version for which `TrueQ` did not work on its own.