# FullForm and the attribute HoldAll

Tags: programming

I have noticed that

```
TrueQ @ (And @@ {False, True, True, True})
```

gives `False` and, on the contrary,

```
TrueQ @ And @@ {False, True, True, True}
```

returns

```
False[False, True, True, True]
```

The disparity is probably explained here: [TrueQ returning False on true statement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55911/trueq-returning-false-on-true-statement): "`TrueQ` does not attempt to resolve equivalencies:`TrueQ` will return `True` only if the input is explicitly `True`". Indeed, by means of

```
a = And @@ {False, True, True, True};
{SameQ[a, True],TrueQ @ a}
```

we get `{False,False}`

But the point now is: why `FullForm[a]` is `False` ?

Reading the help : "`FullForm` acts as a "wrapper", which affects display, but not evaluation". Therefore `FullForm[a]` should give `False[False,True,True,True]`.

My first thought was about the `HoldAll` attribute (which `FullForm` have not) but I was wrong:

```
Quiet[Remove[fullForm]];
fullForm = FullForm;
SetAttributes[fullForm, HoldAll];
Attributes[fullForm]
fullForm[a]
```

still evalutes to `False`. Any hints ? Thanks !

Comment: No: this is precedence of operators: `TrueQ @ And @@ {False, True, True, True}` first evaluates to `TrueQ[And] @@{False, True, True, True}` which then evaluates to `False@@{False,True,True,True}` and then to `False[False, True, True, True]`.

Comment: Of course, `And @@ {False, True, True, True}` immediately becomes `And[False, True, True, True]`, and the short-circuit property of `And[]` has it evaluate to `False`. For `TrueQ @ And @@ {False, True, True, True}`, have a look at `FullForm[Hold[TrueQ @ And @@ {False, True, True, True}]]`.

Comment: Thanks for replies ! (1) About the operators precedence: I smelled something but, strangely, `TrueQ` is not mentioned in `tutorial/OperatorInputForms` (8.0.1.0) and that made me quite doubtful. Now I see. (2) About `FullForm`: I'm still confused: given that `FullForm` and `FullForm @ Hold` are not equivalent, what does it mean "wrapper", as, quoted from help, in the question above ?

Answer (score 3):

1. In `a = And @@ {False, True, True, True};` the right had side is evaluated before making the assignment.  At that point `a` with either be held verbatim as `a` or it will evaluate to `False`.
2. As march noted `TrueQ @ And @@ {False, True, True, True}` is not evaluating in the order you probably think it is.  `TrueQ[And]` works as expected, and this new head (`False`) is Applied to your `List` expression.
3. Indeed `FullForm` acts as a formatting wrapper; it will not prevent things inside it from evaluating.  If you want that try the `HoldForm` wrapper as well:

   ```
   HoldForm[ FullForm[ TrueQ[And][1 + 1, 2 + 2] ] ]
   ```

   > ```
   > TrueQ[And][Plus[1, 1], Plus[2, 2]]
   > ```