# TrueQ returns False

Tags: expression-test

I have coefficient of some expansion:

```
Workingexpansion = 
  tau/n - (A tau^2)/(27 n^3) - (B tau^3)/(5832 n^5);
CoefficientList[Workingexpansion, tau][[2]]
```

> ```
> 1/n
> ```

I know, that, for example, when `i = 2`, this coefficient is equal to `1/n`, where n is integer. I'd like to check whether the coefficient is zero or not. I found some information [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55911/trueq-returning-false-on-true-statement), but, unfortunately it didn't help me.

So this is what I did:

```
Assuming[
  n ∈ Integers, 
  TrueQ[Simplify[CoefficientList[Workingexpansion, tau][[2]]] != 0]]
```

And I get `False`. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Me neither. What is `Workingexpansion`?

Comment: tau/n - (A tau^2)/(27 n^3) - (B tau^3)/(5832 n^5)

Answer (score 4):

You have to wrap the whole equation with `Simplify`, otherwise, `Assuming` cannot become active.

```
Assuming[
 n ∈ Integers,
 TrueQ[
  Simplify[
   CoefficientList[Workingexpansion, tau][[2]] != 0
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

> True

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!